# Extract Bytes At specified location from byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays, data-structures

hello i am new with byte manipulation in java. i already have byte array with flowing format

```
1-> datapacketlength (length of name) (first byte)
2-> name  (second byte + datapacket length)
3-> datapacketlength (length of datetime)
4-> current date and time
```

how can i extract the name and current date and time.`should i use Arrays.copyOfRange() method.`

Regards from

mcd

Comment: How long are the length fields? Is this received from a socket or locally read from a file?

Comment: length field contain one byte and it Would varying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ByteBuffer` and use your current byte array, then use the methods that come with it to get the next float, int etc (such as `buffer.getInt` and `buffer.getFloat`).

You can get a portion of your byte array when you create a new bytebuffer by using the `wrap` method I believe. The possibilities are endless :). To get strings as you asked, you simply need to do something like:

```
 byte[] name = new byte[nameLength];
 buffer.get(name);
 nameString = byteRangeToString(name);
```

where byteRangeToString is a method to return  a new string representation of the byte[] data you pass it.

```
public String byteRangeToString(byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
         return new String(data, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
         /* handle accordingly */
    }
}
```

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

Using copyOfRange() may run you into memory issues if used excessively.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like :

```
int nameLength = 0;
int dateLength = 0;
byte[] nameByteArray;
byte[] dateByteArray

for(int i=0; i<bytesArray.length; i++){
    if(i == 0){
        nameLength = bytesArray[i] & 0xFF;
        nameByteArray = new byte[nameLength];
    }
    else if(i == nameLength+1){
        dateLength = byteArray[i] & 0xFF;
        dateByteArray = new byte[dateLength];
    }
    else if(i < nameLength+1){
        nameByteArray[i-1] = bytesArray[i];
    }
    else{
        dateByteArray[i-(nameLength+1)] = bytesArray[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).